# what' does the "heroes$!:Observable<Hero[]>;"mean?

Tags: angular, typescript

what' does the "heroes$!:Observable<Hero[]>;"mean? And what' does the "heroes$？:Observable<Hero[]>;"mean?

Answer (score 4):

The `!` is the manual type assertion operator to remove `null` and `undefined` from the type. You can read more about [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) here.

The `?` means it's optional, it can be undefined. It's a shortand for `heroes$: Observable<Hero[]> | undefined`. The [documentation for mapping modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) is here.

When you have strict settings enabled in your `tslint.json`, the compiler will complain about class properties that are not initialised where you declared then nor in the consrtuctor. For this you can do two things.

1. Mark them with the optional `?` modifier, or use an [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with `undefined`.
2. Use `!` to manually assert the type, and silence the compiler. With this you actually mean: "You can't know, but I know better this property will allways have a value". This is good when Angular sets the property. (like @Input(), @ViewChild(..., {static: true}))